# Why Activity only opens when you click on the last notice?

Tags: android, android-notifications

my application receives notifications from the server. There may be many and various types. By clicking on the notification must open the MyActivity. But it only opens when you click on the last notice. Pressing the previous notice any results do not give. I need that when you press any notification opens the MyActivity

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification notification   = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm))
                .setTicker("Новое сообщение")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(id++, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong PendingIntent flag, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT): `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` - "the current one should be canceled before generating a new one"

you probably shoud use [PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

4th line in your posted code:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);  // flag change
```

Comment: Now if I click on the notification to open the program. but if it is to roll and click on the rest of the notification program does not open again

Comment: you have linked doc with four flags combinations, why are you asking for final result and code insted of some reading? maybe try `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`. I dont really fully understand what you want to achieve, its possible that you have to modify also `Intent` for Activity adding one of flags from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) (all starts `FLAG_ACTIVITY_`

Comment: helped me flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT. your advice prompted the decision. thanks!

Comment: still would like to ask, can you know how to group notifications? I can not find a solution.

Comment: `Notification.setGroupSummary(true)` and `Notification.setGroup("stringNameOfGroup")`

Comment: I tried it in the first place. messages are still displayed separately